# How do you reference a variable in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have a variable and I have an array in Javascript. What is the proper way to reference the variable inside of an array?

```
const myVariable = "www.site.com"
const myArray = [
 {
  url: myVariable
 }
]
```

I'd like the value of url to be "www.site.com".

Comment: looks fine to me.... Is there a problem you are facing?

Comment: That will copy the value of the variable into the object in the array. It won't keep a permanent link between them -- changing one does not affect the other.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have pointers or variable references. If you want something that can be shared, use an object or array.

Comment: @epascarello yes, but I assumed my error was with my javascript syntax. I'm trying to take graphQL data from a Gatsby useStaticQuery query, assign it to a variable and reference that variable in an array. when I console log the variable it just says [object Object]

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you get when you use an object where a string is required, like `alert(myArray[0])`. If you post your actual code we can help you better.

Comment: @Barmar I see that I had to JSON stringify that to get the values. Now that I see the complex object returned, I don't think my problem here is my javascript syntax. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you to do that: `myArray[0].url`

If you fill your array with objects, you can access to properties of object un array using `myArray[index].myProperty`

Answer (score 0):

If you need `url` to be changed when variable `myVariable` gets changed - wrap it in object
like

```
const myVariableObject = {
  url: "www.site.com"
 };
const myArray = [myVariableObject];
```

Otherwise you'll get `url: "www.site.com"` without any relationship to previous variable.